# MKAnnotationView layer is not of expected type: MKLayer

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

So my code works fine but my logger is riddled with this message. Is there a way to get rid of it or suppress it?

**PostAnnotation.swift**

```
class PostAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {

    //MARK: properties
    let post: Post

    //MARK: initialization
    init(post: Post) {
        self.post = post
        super.init()
        self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: post.latitude, longitude: post.longitude)
        self.title = post.title
        self.subtitle = post.timeString()
    }

}
```

**Adding the annotation**

```
let annotation = PostAnnotation(post: post)
self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

**func mapView**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "pin") as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    if let annotation = annotation as? PostAnnotation {
        annotationView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.blue
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
        annotationView?.animatesDrop = true
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Removing this function removes the message

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?   I started hitting the same message with Xcode 9 GM.   The MKPinAnnotationView call is triggering my occurrence.

Comment: @refactor Xcode 9 GM

Comment: I've seen this error since at least Xcode 9 beta 4.

Comment: I hadn't noticed it before Xcode GM, but a check using Xcode 9 beta 6 shows it present in that log.  So I don't know when Xcode had the first occurrence of that message in my project.  Sorry that is no help in getting rid of or suppressing the message.

Comment: @Refactor glad to know I'm not alone

Comment: It seems a bug... I don't see this error with `MKMarkerAnnotationView`.

Answer (score 19):

This is a bug in iOS 11, since `MKLayer` is not a public class.

I'd simply ignore the message, but if it's bothering you: To silence this warning, you can set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE=disable` in the scheme's environment page. Beware though, you will silence other OS warnings as well.

[image: Scheme Editor]