# Apple Maps, Raster Overlays Above Labels - Failed to decode

Tags: ios, ios11

After migrating to the new iOS 11. We are seeing this new error. Not only we are facing the error but the whole UI is sluggish.

This is a native iOS app written in obj-c. We are not seeing the error in ios 10.2 or earlier. Any ideas?

Comment: As of today, the ios maps are really sluggish on ios 11. You can load the native apple maps app and it is super slow. We have verified this on multiple macs.

Comment: Here is the console error I see... `[VKDefault] Tile 20831.46868.17 (128) in current unloaded state for 0.00 seconds - Raster Overlays Above Labels - Failed to decode (terminal) (0.00 sec)`

Comment: We are just waiting for the new ios simulator drop!

Comment: It's not working in the device as well

Comment: Same here. I'm using multiple MKOverlay to trace devices on map. With iOS 11 I have the same messages on console. I have this error running the app on device.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with iOS11 in my Swift MapKit App.
The log console is completely filled with

    2017-10-04 14:07:58.960143-0700 MyAppName[294:16118] [VKDefault] Tile 7347.4937.13 (128) in current unloaded state for 0.01 seconds - Raster Overlays Above Labels - Failed to decode (terminal) (0.01 sec)
    2017-10-04 14:07:58.960219-0700 MyAppName[294:16118] [VKDefault] Tile 7348.4935.13 (128) in current unloaded state for 0.01 seconds - Raster Overlays Above Labels - Failed to decode (terminal) (0.01 sec)

Comment: Same issue here and still haven't seen any resolution or information regarding this.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on iOS 11. Before the above mentioned errors, there are also the following errors (not present on iOS 10): `[GEODBWriter] /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/GeoServices/GeoServices-1350.30.7.28.6/GEODBWriter.mm:601 Could not open database (/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.geod/MapTiles/MapTiles.sqlitedb): (14) unable to open database file` and a bunch of SQL errors like `[logging] API called with NULL prepared statement` and `[logging] misuse at line 84067 of [2b0954060f]`.

Comment: While trying to find the source of memory loss, I came upon this. I wonder if the decode is failing and the code doesn't cleanup the allocated tile memory. `   5.57 MB     100.0% 36687   __49-[VKTileSource decodeData:downloadKey:sourceKey:]_block_invoke
`

Comment: There is know issue with the gps chip with the ios 11 and they have fixed it in ios 11.1 beta 5 developer version. So the problems with map issues are going to be solved with that update.

Comment: Unfortunately, contrary to the suggestion above, the errors are still present in 11.1.

Comment: Any update on a fix?

Comment: Have to same Problem.

Comment: Have the same issue in iOS 11.4.1, I am running on the device. the error is "[VKDefault] Tile 19303.24621.16 (128) in current unloaded state for 0.02 seconds - Raster Overlays Above Labels - Failed to decode (terminal) (0.02 sec)" But working correctly on iOS 12.1

Answer (score 17):

It's a known bug that shouldn't pop up. It's on Apple's side, not yours. It's still not fixed as of 11.1, although word is getting out that it might be fixed as of 11.2. Simply ignore it.

Also, you may get an error like this if you are working with annotations on maps:

"MKAnnotationView layer is not of expected type: MKLayer"

Ignore this as well for the same reasons as stated above. If you want to, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205686/mkannotationview-layer-is-not-of-expected-type-mklayer) and see this guy's recommendation for silencing these errors if they are bothering you.

I just tried what the guy up there recommended, and it works at silencing the warning so you won't see it (be careful though, it will also silence other warnings that could be important if they come up).

Steps that need to be done:

1) Click on "Product", scroll down to "Scheme", and click "Edit Scheme".
2) Click "Run" on the menu on the left.
3) Press the + button in the "Environment Variables" section and type in "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE" under name.
4) Type in "disable" under value.
5) Press the "Close" button and you are done.

Comment: Still happening with Xcode 9.2 release (9C40b) and iOS 11.2 simulator. :(

Comment: In Xcode 9.2 following the steps you provided prevents NSLog's from appearing. Is there a fix that doesn't prevent NSLog's from showing up?

Comment: This tip still worked for me in Xcode 9.2 beta--4 (macOS 10.13.3), thanks. Log was spammed with these messages to the point where I couldn't find my own.

Comment: Easy to say to ignore this if it keeps on flooding your logs thereby removing your own, useful, logs because they just scroll out of the buffer.

Comment: Still seeing this on Xcode 12.4 (12D4e) using an iPhone 12 simulator running iOS 14.4